# What is the probability that a random point would lie in this inscribed circle?

Tags: probability, area, geometric-probability

Take the unit square and inscribe a circle $Q$. Then take one of the corners (say the upper-left one) and inscribe a circle $Q'$ in that space (so the circle touch the square twice and $Q$ once). Let $(X_n,Y_n)$ be uniformly distributed on $[0,1]^2$. What is $\mathbb P((X_1,Y_1)\in Q')$?

My motivation for this question is of course the geometrical one, what is the area of said circle. This is the method I came up with, but I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Draw the picture with $Q$ and $Q'$. You realise that there's two axes of symmetry, so you can just take one fourth of the picture (that includes one quarter of $Q$ and half of $Q'$. Draw that triangle. This triangle has side lengths $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$. Note that $Q$ has radius one. That means that the distance from the intersection of $Q$ and $Q'$ to the end of the triangle is $\frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{2}$. Now draw the radius of $Q'$, perpendicular to the hypotenuse. Another small triangle appears, with one side being the radius of $Q'$. Can you now form an equation for the sides of this triangle?

Comment: You use the term "intersect" - do you really mean "touch"?

Comment: BTW, what method is here?

Comment: Sure, by "intersect" I mean "touch."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to Matti's comment. Starting out from the same symmetric top quarter, you know that we have a right triangle, with the corner angles being at $45^\circ$. Now go to the center of the smaller inscribed half-circle and draw a line from the center to the intersection with the square. You can now state an equation about $\sin 45^\circ$ in terms of the small radius $a$.

The equation should look something like this. (For simplicity, I have assumed that the radius of the large circle is 1)

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} &=& \frac{a}{\sqrt{2}-(1+a)}\\
a &=& 3 - 2\sqrt{2}
\end{eqnarray}

To answer your question, the probability of landing in one small circle on the unit square is 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\pi a^2}{4} = 0.0231
\end{equation}